# Repo tool. send tags appropriate to manifest.xml

Tags: git, bash, version-control, tags, repo

i have manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch=".." name="origin" review="nda.com"/>

  <default remote="origin" revision="release/nda/phase3" sync-j="4"/>

  <project name="nda-nda" revision="6f76200b8ab9fed4f52c4f58ae36b722dabc1116" upstream="phase2"/>
  <project name="ndda" revision="f849e04438191616bd8b39367249ba2b4824111c" upstream="phase2"/>
  <project name="nda/guidance-tests" path="tools/guidance-tests" revision="37751838644275ee87d01f604b49f0af64fe4f31" upstream="nda2"/>
  <project name="auto-character-recognition" revision="2ea1ffc90185a00abfd621ae58919b728503d975" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="auto-tools" revision="c3db989d8959a20f11c872af25dc655a02a18e49" upstream="master"/>
  <project name="cdvox/nda-nvp" path="nda-nvp" revision="6a7aed71adf71b90c5192b521523a401abdd800c" upstream="phase2"/>
  <project name="external/googlenda" revision="1e932a2dd63b572bc19b7be6811b02a6336b8db9" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="external/rapidjson" revision="a717a565e55da510a43ad1546797196d9071c41e" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="mobility-graph" path="ndda/core/myndda/" revision="bb530f2a425b6e27ece6617fe9ca309d62024c9c" upstream="nda-phase2"/>
  <project name="nda/main" path="nda" revision="95e5ebcf0fb339a78bd176566e9926a54ad1e0aa" upstream="nda2"/>
  <project name="nda/nda-config" path="nda_config" revision="246a0b74c773b4e6d3082eb11cef2643e7dddb73" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/ndaing/libev" path="ndaing/ev" revision="fa705c3882d0df14a795d980494e7765d8871594" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/ndaing/libisoline" path="ndaing/isoline" revision="788627f319c88d189aa8ba56676cc19d20fd139a" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/wxtest/resources" path="nda/apps/wxtest/external/resources" revision="096fec72874f82b228f095e3941f839934127976" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/Integration" path="Integration" revision="2464df763d90bb36a221118f5b96fe23a770739f" upstream="phase2"/>
  <project name="nda/IntegrationSimulator" path="IntegrationSimulator" revision="3287873f47182070e405bc993911d3bd55af6600" upstream="phase2"/>
  <project name="nda/Tools" path="Tools" revision="8896d6994bc2d07d87adafbbcd9ba68679fb5564" upstream="phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/qhttpserver" path="qhttpserver" revision="4462f71cc480c22ae5a9880813402183e1761533" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
  <project name="nda/sqlcipher" path="sqlcipher" revision="bcf4e1c713bbefc56c2aeaebefcae6c2a3d4e375" upstream="release/nda/phase3"/>
</manifest>
```

my bash script

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

rm -rf Auto-tools


sed -i 's/".."/"ssh:\/\/my_nda_user@my_nda_server:29418"/g' manifest.xml
repo forall -c git tag -a $TAG_NAME -m "${TAG_NAME}" && git push origin
```

but get

> Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message and
>   maintain the traditional behavior, use:
>
> git config --global push.default matching
>
> To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>
> git config --global push.default simple
>
> When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
>   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
>
> Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
>   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
>   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.
>
> See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further
>   information. (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the
>   similar mode 'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older
>   versions of Git)
>
> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin master
> ```
>
> Build step 'Conditional steps (multiple)' marked build as failure

Also was trying:

repo forall -c git config --global push.default matching
and
repo forall -c git config --global push.default simple

but got the same

Please help me to send tags to all repositories on appropriateto manifest.xml  commit.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to push all tags in remote, you should use `--tags` for `git push`. Such as `git push origin --tags`.

Comment: Did you solve it by add --tag for `git push` in your manifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.

This is the key issue about your question, I think.

After you run `repo sync`, your local git repository is in `detached header` status, there is no any upstream information for each of your local branch, so git do not know which remote branch should push to, and show your error message.

you should run `git checkout --track` to switch branch of local repository firstly before run `git push origin`.